# How to resume android app after HDMI reconnect

Tags: android, resume, disconnect, hdmi

What must be done to resume an app after `HDMI` is reconnected?  I have an app that plays a video and I'd like the video to pause when `HDMI` is disconnected and then resume when `HDMI` is reconnected.  I am able to use a `BroadCastReceiver` to listen for `ACTION_HDMI_AUDIO_PLUG` events and I can pause the video in the `onPause()` event.

When the `HDMI` is disconnected, I see that the `onPause()` and `onStop()` events fire.  Reconnecting the `HDMI` does not invoke an `onResume()` event, presumably because the `onStop()` event has been fired and the app is no longer running.  Is there any way to prevent the app from completely shutting down when the `HDMI` is disconnected?

Comment: Custom ROM/rooted or stock non-rooted consumer device?

Comment: It's actually an Amazon Fire TV app that will also get ported to Android TV as well.  So non-rooted, consumer device.